# how to make select have each number in a range

Tags: html

Is it possible to easily setup a select element in html have a entry for every number in a range (ie 1 to 30) without using 30 lines in my html document?

Comment: Use some sort of templating, server side or client side. Language doesn't matter.

Comment: yes and no.  yes you don't need 30 lines.  no; you do need 30 option elements.

Comment: You need to javascript or jquery or server side scripting, can't do only with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

No, but if your application is going to run on a few modern browsers, you could consider using the new HTML5 form controls, like range, or number.

```
<input type="number" name="foo" min="1" max="30">

<input type="range" name="bar" min="1" max="30">
```

The support for this can be found at http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms

Answer (score 1):

if you aren't opposed to using PHP, PHP makes it super easy!

```
<select>
<?php
for($i = 1; $i<31; $i++){
    echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```